# find all recipe ingredients in the table

Tags: sql

I have two tables. In the first table, all the recipes, in the second, the ingredients of the recipes

Recipes

| RecipeId | Name |
| --- | --- |
| 789 | Pizza |
| 790 | Soup |
| 791 | Sushi |
| 792 | Cake |
| 793 | Sandwich |
| 794 | Bread |
| 795 | Sausage |

Ingredients

| id | RecipeId | Name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 789 | Flour |
| 2 | 789 | Water |
| 795 | 789 | Sausage |
| 3 | 789 | Olives |
| 4 | 789 | Salt |
| 794 | 793 | Bread |
| 795 | 793 | Sausage |
| 1 | 794 | Flour |
| 2 | 794 | Water |
| 4 | 794 | Salt |
| 5 | 795 | Ground meat |
| 4 | 795 | Salt |

How can I find the recipe with the most ingredients, including all ingredients, such as a sandwich, which has bread (flour, water, salt) and sausages (ground meat and salt) = 5 ingredients? using sql query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a `RANK()` based approach here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT RecipeId, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
    FROM Ingredients
    GROUP BY RecipeId
)

SELECT r.*
FROM Recipes r
WHERE RecipeId IN (SELECT RecipeId FROM cte WHERE rnk = 1);
```